# Completly deinstall and remove Elasticsearch for complete restart and begin new

Tags: elasticsearch

After experimenting with Elasticsearch I'm searching for a way to completely remove everything concerning Elasticsearch on my server. I made quite a few mistakes and want to start completely new with a new installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply find the Java process that Elasticsearch is in and kill, or use `curl -XPOST /*Your Ip*/:9200/_shutdown`.

Then remove Elasticsearch from your system by simply deleting the ES files/folder.

Various different setups could require different deletion methods (linux use `rm -rf` ES dirs, windows the good ol' delete button will work, logstash may require additional steps) but as a general rule it's quite simply to remove.

If you wish to remove only the data you can delete the data dir, or wipe all your indexes and reindex.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly, I did:
1.) curl -XPOST /*Your Ip*/:9200/_shutdown
2.) find . -name "*elastic*" -print  (to find all files and folders containing "elastic")
3.) rm -rf /*file*/   (to delete all found files, I didn't remove ALL found files, I left the ones in the directory of composer)

Answer (score -1):

use the following command to know the pid of the node already running.

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/process'

It took me an hour to find out the way to kill the node and could finally do it after using this command in the terminal window.

**For Linux users:

> kill -9 {pid}

** will terminate the elasticsearch from the RAM. And then you can delete as the other answers suggest.